# Como correr Django en python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

estoy trabajando con Django en python 2.7, para eso hago uso de virtualenv, pip, el conector de mysql, etc. Tengo predefinido python 3.5 en bash, pero aun asi cuando ejecuto ./manage.py shell se ejecuta con python 2.7. Como hago para cambiarlo a python 3.5?
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Crea un archivo de requisitos en tu entorno actual:

  ```
  $ pip freeze > requisitos.txt
  ```
- Luego desactiva tu entorno actual:

  ```
  $ deactivate
  ```
- A continuación crea un nuevo entorno virtual con Python 3.5, ya que tienes predefinido este intérprete:

  ```
  $ python -m venv genarito
  ```
- Luego activas este nuevo entorno:

  ```
  $ source genarito/bin/activate
  ```
- (opcional) Si lo consideras necesario, puedes actualizar `pip`

  ```
  (genarito) $ pip install --upgrade pip
  ```
- Por último, instalas los requisitos:

  ```
  (genarito) $ pip install -r requisitos.txt
  ```

Y eso es todo.

> Verifica que usas el conector correcto para MySQL, creo tal vez sea el único cambio que requieras: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Comment: Me funcionó de 10!!!! Mil gracias! Hubo un error con el conector de mysql como dijiste, pero ya voy a ver como soluciono eso! Nuevamente gracias. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Primero asegúrate que tienes el virtualenv activado. 
Luego, que la versión de python instalada en ese virtualenv, es la versión 3.x y no 2.7  o 2.x.

Para comprobarlo, simplemente activa el virtualenv e introduce en la shell:

`python -V`

Esto te dará la versión instalada, y si no es la correcta, podrás generar un nuevo virtualenv o bien instalar la versión correcta.

Esta sería la opción por defecto.

Si quieres instalar ambas versiones de python, simplemente, a la hora de llamar al comando ./manage.py, hazlo de la siguiente forma:

´python3 ./manage.py shell´

Por último recomendarte instalar ipython, que es muy útil cuando trabajas en la shell de python o django.

Answer (score 1):

Python3.5 trae un sistema de entorno por defecto llamado `pyvenv` que funciona igual que virtualenv.

Solo debes correr en la terminal:

```
$ pyvenv env
$ source env/bin/activate
```

Y de ahi en adelante puedes instalar django y el resto de paquetes con pip. El entorno por defecto ejecutará python3.5 cuando ejecutes cualquier comando como `python manage.py migrate`